# ASIHTTPRequest Post request fails while works via HTTPClient

Tags: objective-c, ios, post, asihttprequest

As stated in title, I send a `POST` request using `ASIHTTPRequest` and it fails, but the same `POST` request works in `HTTPClient`, am I doing something wrong?

```
- (void)postData:(NSData *)postData {
    //...
    NSMutableData *mutableData = [postData.mutableCopy autorelease];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setPostBody:mutableData];
    [request setPostLength:mutableData.length];
    //....
}
```

Comment: How does it exactly fails? What error do you get? Please help us to help you.

Comment: @AmarKulo it failed with some server error, something like 500, but it works when I tried the same request using a dedicated program to send it like http client.

Comment: Server error 500 is error on the server, so it basically means that you are sending wrong request. I would set up sniffer and track both requests and see what's the difference and there you will find answer why it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not quite enough in all cases, at least I also had to add the correct Content-Type header to the request:

```
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"];
[request appendPostData:[theString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]
```

Answer (score 1):

OK I found the problem, for some reason I cannot do

`[request setPostBody]`

I have to use

`[request appendPostData:[theString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]`

instead.