# Invalid Index on post via ASync NSURLConnection

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

Im posting data from IOS to a php script. Since changing from a Sync request to an Async one i have been unable to get the upload to work.

OK so i have the following errors in my web server log

```
[Sat Nov 28 13:18:56 2015] [error] [client 80.6.199.219:38875] AH01215: PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in public_html/iphone2/php.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0: public_html/iphone2/UploadImage.php
[Sat Nov 28 13:18:56 2015] [error] [client 80.6.199.219:38875] AH01215: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: user_id in public_html/iphone2/UploadImage.php on line 8: public_html/iphone2/UploadImage.php
[Sat Nov 28 13:18:56 2015] [error] [client 80.6.199.219:38875] AH01215: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: RequestID in public_html/iphone2/UploadImage.php on line 9: public_html/iphone2/UploadImage.php
[Sat Nov 28 13:18:56 2015] [error] [client 80.6.199.219:38875] AH01215: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: base64 in public_html/iphone2/UploadImage.php on line 10: public_html/iphone2/UploadImage.php
500kgiveaway.co.uk [Sat Nov 28 13:18:56 2015] [error] [client 80.6.199.219:38875] AH01215: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: base64_thumb in ublic_html/iphone2/UploadImage.php on line 11: public_html/iphone2/UploadImage.php
[Sat Nov 28 13:18:56 2015] [error] [client 80.6.199.219:38875] AH01215: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: ImageName in public_html/iphone2/UploadImage.php on line 14: public_html/iphone2/UploadImage.php
[Sat Nov 28 13:18:56 2015] [error] [client 80.6.199.219:38875] AH01215: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: ImageName in /home/sites/500kgiveaway.co.uk/public_html/iphone2/UploadImage.php on line 13: /home/sites/500kgiveaway.co.uk/public_html/iphone2/UploadImage.php
500kgiveaway.co.uk [Sat Nov 28 13:18:56 2015] [error] [client 80.6.199.219:38875] AH01215: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: ImageName in /home/sites/500kgiveaway.co.uk/public_html/iphone2/UploadImage.php on line 30: /home/sites/500kgiveaway.co.uk/public_html/iphone2/UploadImage.php
500kgiveaway.co.uk [Sat Nov 28 13:18:56 2015] [error] [client 80.6.199.219:38875] AH01215: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: ImageName in public_html/iphone2/UploadImage.php on line 42: public_html/iphone2/UploadImage.php
500kgiveaway.co.uk [Sat Nov 28 13:18:56 2015] [error] [client 80.6.199.219:38875] AH01215: PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(upload/images/): failed to open stream: Is a directory in public_html/iphone2/UploadImage.php on line 42: public_html/iphone2/UploadImage.php
```

Here is the code to send the post request

```
- (void)uploadToServer:(NSString *)base64Large thumb:(NSString *)base64Thumb {

    NSString *poststring = @"";

    long currentTime = (long)(NSTimeInterval)([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
    NSString *currentTimeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",currentTime];
    NSString *fileName = [currentTimeString stringByAppendingString:@".jpg"];

    NSString *postImageName = @"ImageName=%imagename%&";
    postImageName =[postImageName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%imagename%" withString:fileName];

    poststring = [poststring stringByAppendingString:postImageName];


    NSString *postUserID = @"user_id=%UserID%&";
    postUserID =[postUserID stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%UserID%" withString:@"2"];

    poststring = [poststring stringByAppendingString:postUserID];

    NSString *postRequestListID = @"RequestID=%RLID%&";
    postRequestListID =[postRequestListID stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%RLID%" withString:self.golbalRequestListID];

    poststring = [poststring stringByAppendingString:postRequestListID];

    NSString *postBase64 = @"base64=%B64%&";
    postBase64 =[postBase64 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%B64%" withString:base64Large];
    postBase64 = [postBase64 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];

    poststring = [poststring stringByAppendingString:postBase64];

    NSString *postBase64thumb = @"base64_thumb=%B64T%&";
    postBase64thumb =[postBase64thumb stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%B64T%" withString:base64Thumb];
    postBase64thumb = [postBase64thumb stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];

    poststring = [poststring stringByAppendingString:postBase64thumb];


    //create the request

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"iphone2/UploadImage.php"]];

    //Specify that it will be a post request
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

        //This is how we set header fields
    [request setValue:@"application/xml: charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    //convert your data and set your requests httpbody property
    NSData *requestBodyData = [poststring dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData;


    //create url connection and fire request
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];




}
```

The post request contains a number of entries for a database and 2 images in base64 (1 the full size image about 5-7mb and a thumbnail versioin (1-2mb))

As i said before this was working perfectly when using the Sync method.

I am not receiving any errors within xcode and when i monitor the didSendBodyData method i can see the app sending the data.

I did think that it may be a problem with the post request, however i cant find a way of checking if it valid. I also throught that it may be a problem with the amount of data that i was sending, so i increased the post limit to 20MB

honestly, i cant think of what else the problem may be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a problem with the value of the header field

```
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

The influence was taken from the following post

[ASIHTTPRequest Post request fails while works via HTTPClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210222/asihttprequest-post-request-fails-while-works-via-httpclient)

i Hope this helps someone else